# SQLITE insert into database issue Windows Phone C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am totally new in WP development, but I am interested to learn.

I have a little problem when I try to insert data into my SQLITE database.  The weird thing is when I input the data there is no problem and it doesn't throw an exception.

When I try to close my apps and open it again from simulator the data is showing, but when I open my database.sqlite from Sqlite manager firefox addons, the data is not there.  The table is still empty.

Please help me out.

```cs
private void btnAddExpense_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime datenow = DateTime.Now;
            String format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
            String d = datenow.ToString(format);

            String formatid = "yyyyMMddHHmmss";
            String id = datenow.ToString(formatid);

            int rec;
            String strInsert = " Insert into Expense (date,id_category,nominal,detail,icon) values (@date,@id_category,@nominal,@detail,@icon)";


            Expense tst = new Expense
                {
                    date = d,
                    id_category = cat,
                    nominal = amount.Text,
                    detail = detail_txt.Text,
                    icon = iconUrl,
                };
                rec = (Application.Current as App).db.Insert<Expense>(tst, strInsert);
                if (rec == 1)
                    MessageBox.Show("Row inserted!");
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Row NOT inserted.");
        }
```

and I use Dbhelper.cs to insert data

```
public int Insert<T>(T obj, string statement) where T : new()
        {
            try
            {
                Open();
                SQLiteCommand cmd = db.CreateCommand(statement);
                int rec = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(obj);

                return rec;

            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Insert failed: " + ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: Are you sure that you are looking in the right location with your sqlite manager in Firefox?

Comment: hey, amit thanks for reply, yup i am sure i am in the right location, the other weird things is, when i closed my simulator and start debugging it again, the data is empty :(

Comment: How are you opening your SQLite db file in firefox? You need to extract the file from the emulator first. Also note that when you rebuild from within Visual Studio, all created files will be wiped.

Comment: .NET framework already has the embedded RDBMS engine you can use, namely sqlce + entity framework. Why use a 3-rd party one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlite data are copied to isolated storage first, then you insert record to table. So, if you want to view newest DB, you must open file .sqlite in isolated storage, not at project folder.